# How i put string in XmlElement in XmlDocument

Tags: xml

How it is possible to put a string in XmlElement like this example:

`<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it that way:

```
       XmlElement Document = doc.CreateElement("Document");
            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
            attr.Value = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03";
            Document.Attributes.Append(attr);
            XmlAttribute attr1 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
            attr1.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            Document.Attributes.Append(attr1);
```